# Error en función HSQL: "wrong or missing data impact clause in declaration"

Tags: sql

Tengo un error creando la siguien function en HSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getmax ()
   RETURNS INT
   BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE max_event INT;
     SET max_event = SELECT MAX(tabla_id) FROM tabla;
     RETURN max_event;
   END
$$
```

Error:

> wrong or missing data impact clause in declaration
>
> ERROR: declaración incorrecta ya que no respeta la restricción  sobre
>   datos, parámetro SQL DATA: READS SQL in statement

No logro entender el error, ya busque en la documentación de HSQL y muchas otras paginas, pero no logro resolverlo.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

He logrado solucionarlo, dejo la respuesta en caso de que alguien mas la necesite.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getmax ()
   RETURNS INT
    READS SQL DATA
     RETURN (SELECT MAX(tabla_id) FROM tabla)
$$
```